# Trigger the signal only if two consecutive crossing is in same direction

Tags: pine-script

I have a simple pine script to change the color of the candle when its crosses the kijun line. What I want to achieve is the trigger should only happen if two of the crossings are in the same direction.

Tried but could not come up with a good solution.

```
study(title="KijCrossTest", shorttitle="KijCrossTest", overlay = false )


conversionPeriods = input(9, minval=1),
basePeriods = input(26, minval=1)
laggingSpan2Periods = input(52, minval=1, title="Lagging Span 2 
Periods"),
displacement = input(26, minval=1)
donchian(len) => avg(lowest(len), highest(len))
conversionLine = donchian(conversionPeriods)
baseLine = donchian(basePeriods)
leadLine1 = avg(conversionLine, baseLine)
leadLine2 = donchian(laggingSpan2Periods)
midtk = (conversionLine+baseLine)/2


long  = iff ( (close > baseLine)  and (low<=baseLine) and (close>open) 
,1, -1)

short = iff ( (close < baseLine)and (high>=baseLine) and (close<open) 
,-1, 1)



barcolor(long == 1 ? lime: short == -1 ? red:close < open? black : white)

plot(long, title="long", style=line, linewidth=1, color=green )
plot(short, title="short", style=line, linewidth=1, color=red )
```

[image]

Comment: are you aware of the `crossover()` and `crossunder()` functions ? [crossover](https://www.tradingview.com/study-script-reference/#fun_crossover) [crossunder](https://www.tradingview.com/study-script-reference/#fun_crossunder)

Comment: i was not until now, will check it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=3
study("My Script", overlay=true, max_bars_back=5000)

s1 = sma(close, 10)
s2 = sma(close, 200)

plot(s1, color=red)
plot(s2, color=green)

crossed = cross(s1, s2)

plot(crossed ? 100 : 0, color=green, style=histogram)

//NOTE: used crosseed[1], because barssince(crosseed) would return 0
since = barssince(crossed[1])

colorTheSame(s) => 
    close > open == close[s] > open[s]

triggered = crossed and colorTheSame(since)

plot(triggered ? 100 : 0)
```

I suppose this's close to what you are looking for. I used sma instead your series as an example

Comment: Thanks Michel, I am a beginner in this script so not quite sure what many of these means. If its not too much to ask, Is it possible to use the code i used above with yours, so i can compare with what i want to achieve. Learned new functions from your code like barssince. Thanks

Comment: What i am trying to achieve , lets say there is an SMA or kijun  or any line, the trigger should be when a candle cross that line in the same direction twice. If there is any CLOSE in the opposite direction between the two candles crossing in same direction , it should not be triggered.